# a single copy of a shared module’s code segment can be shared?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker

I'm reading a textbook which says:

> modern systems compile the code segments of shared modules so that
> they can be loaded anywhere in memory without having to be modified by
> the linker. With this approach, a single copy of a shared module’s
> code segment can be shared by an unlimited number of processes and
> each process will still get its own copy of the read/write data
> segment.

But how does each process get its own copy of the data segment of shared modules? isn't it a conflict? for example the address in memory for data segement of a shared library is 0x400500 to 0x400600 and the address for code segement is 0x400600 to 0x400700.

0x400600 to 0x400700  can be shared by multiple processes since functions don't have state, but if 0x400500 to 0x400600 is also shared by multiple processes, any process that makes a modification(e.g. on a global variable) will affect other processes, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is accomplished by **virtual memory**.  The memory space used by a given process is completely separate from the memory space used by other processors.  The kernel maps a process's virtual memory to a piece of physical memory.

So for the data segment of a shared library, two processes may have the same virtual memory address for that segment but each is mapped to a different physical memory segment.  For the code segment of the library, both processes virtual memory can map to the same physical memory since the segment is read only.

Comment: Quite so. The problem here is the careless using of the term "in memory" in the original quote. This is a vague term in modern computing, because "in memory" has multiple meanings. I guess the writer assumes that readers will all understand the concepts of virtual memory, and will fill in the details that he or she couldn't be bothered to provide.